# Get all classes within constrains

Tags: java, reflection

Im trying to make a generic instance mapper from an SQLite DB to my project logic layer.
Each entry in the mapper is an instance of some class "DAL< name >" for example `DALProduct` all in the same package that extends class `DALObject` with the following structure:

```
public abstract class DALObject{
  abstract String getCreate();
  ... //other logic
}
```

Using reflection I can easily call the `getCreate` method on each class and get what I need from it.
The issue is that I don't know how many child classes `DALObject` will have and i want a mapper that won't need to be touched when a new one is added.

I know that you can get all child classes of `DALObject`s that have been loaded but I run this code at the very start of my program before I load any of the classes.

Any ideas? I have a pretty big constraint case so maybe I can somehow hack it together.

Comment: Is this for Android or a desktop/server application?

Comment: Desktop application.

Comment: Why do you use Reflection to call the `getCreate` method? If you have an instance of `DALObject` (a subclass of it), you can just invoke `getCreate()` on it using plain Java. Regarding your question, the standard approach for dynamic discovery of implementations is [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). For modular Java software, it’s a language feature, which means, you get compile-time checking and good runtime performance.

Comment: Could you please expend on how i may use ServiceLoader to get the subclasses?  I would much prefer to use it if possible but i cant find it in the documentation.

Comment: You only need to click on the link in my previous comment. In case your browser doesn’t highlight it, the word [`ServiceLoader`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) itself is linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such task is only possible by scanning every class on the classpath (which, depending on how many libraries you use, are usually *a lot*) and see if it extends DALObject.

If you want to go that route, the [org.reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) library can help you with that:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.package",
    Reflector.class.getClassLoader(), new SubTypesScanner(false));
Set<Class<? extends Module>> modules = reflections.getSubTypesOf(DALObject.class);
```

For performance reasons, I highly recommend doing this scan once during startup of your application and store the results.

As an alternative approach (I did not bother with generic type safety of `Class` here, this is to be implemented):

```
public abstract class DALObject {
    public static List<Class> subTypes = new ArrayList<>();

    public DALObject() {
        DALObject.subTypes.add(this.getClass());
    }
}
```

Obviously this only works if you instantiate objects of the subclasses somewhere, if your `getCreate` is meant to do that in the first place, my suggestion will obviously not work.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a perfect instance of when to use an annotation. You could define the annotation before the declaration of each class, indicating that the class has some meta-data about 'DALObjects'. Then you could use [Reflections](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.reflections/reflections/0.9.12) or some similar library to easily find all Class objects with this annotation.

For example;

```java
@Target(value=TYPE)
public @interface DALObject {

}
```

```java
@DALObject
public class MyDALObject {

}
```

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .setScanners(new TypeAnnotationsScanner()));

Set<Class<?>> annotatedWithDALObject = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(DALObject.class);
```

Comment: The reflections library scans the classpath for annotations - if you go that route, you could also scan for subtypes right away (Reflections can do that, too - just use a `SubTypeScanner` instead of `TypeAnnotationScanner`). It makes no difference.

Comment: That is a great point, but I wasn't certain if OP was using DALObject as a base class or if it was an example of a class that has DAL in it. I could have asked for clarification, great point.

Comment: As the question does contain code within DALObject, amongst it the `... //other logic` part along with an abstract class, I do think assuming it's used as a base class is a relatively safe bet. I get your point though.

Comment: I re-read the question and you're correct, he does indicate it clearly. I should have put more time into reading the question instead of answering. Thanks for the heads up eh!

Answer (score 0):

Last I know, Reflections isn't well supported (only minor changes in years) and still [doesn't work with modules](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/issues/186).
Instead, I'd recommend using [ClassGraph](https://github.com/classgraph/classgraph), which is ultra-actively maintained, and works with modules, weird class loaders and what not.

You'd find `DALObject` implementations like this:

```
ScanResult scanResults = new ClassGraph()
    .acceptPackages(packages) //skip to scan ALL packages
    .enableAllInfo() //Not necessary but gives you more info to filter on, if needed
    .initializeLoadedClasses()
    .scan();

//You can cache, or serialize scanResults using scanResults.toJSON()

List<Class<?>> impls = scanResults.getAllClasses().stream()
    .filter(impl -> impl.extendsSuperclass(DALObject.getName()))
    // or impl.implementsInterface(DALObject.getName()) if DALObject is an interface
    .flatMap(info -> info.loadClass()) //or load the class yourself if you need to customize the logic
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```